# Java compareTo array sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, compareto

I have two classes `Main` and `Object`. I need to sort the objects in array in ascending order according to its value. I return -1, 1, and 0 from compareTo and I need to run a for loop accordingly to sort my array. I don't want to use Arrays.sort, I need to do it manually. The sorting part n the `Main` class does not work. Any help could be useful. Thank you.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Object[] arr = new Object[6];

    arr[0] = new Object(2);
    arr[1] = new Object(5);
    arr[2] = new Object(3);
    arr[3] = new Object(1);
    arr[4] = new Object(6);
    arr[5] = new Object(4);

    System.out.println("List of instances");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println(arr[i].getValue());
    }

    System.out.println();

    Object tempVar;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

            int result = arr[i].compareTo(arr[i]);

            if (result == -1) {
                tempVar = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = tempVar;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("List of sorted instances");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(arr[i].getValue());
    }

}
```

}

```
public class Object implements Comparable<Object> {

private int value;

public Object(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public int getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    int result = 0;

    if (this.value > o.getValue()) {
        result = 1;
    } else if (this.value < o.getValue()) {
        result = -1;
    } else if (this.value == o.getValue()) {
        result = 0;
    }

    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: Naming a class `Object` is a very bad idea...

Comment: 'int result = arr[i].compareTo(arr[i]);' .... wont that line always return 0? you are comparing the same index of the array

Comment: Is that homework? Your `Object` class is already implemented in Java: check `Integer`

Comment: @Matthieu: My feeling is that of course it's homework. Why else would he have gawd-awful requirements such as, `"you must sort without using Arrays.sort(...)"`?

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels what difference does it really make if it was an assignment. I'm trying to learn.

Comment: @JVTura try googling sorting algorithms, there are lots of them out there... are you trying to sort with a specific efficiency?

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels in case if you haven't noticed, that code above is the "attempt to a solution". Please do not comment and waste your and my time. Thumb down questions and save the world!

Comment: I do not see a *specific* question here. Do you have one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to loop over *all* elements of a collection, then don't use a fixed value like the `5` here:

```
System.out.println("List of instances");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
```

Use `arr.length` instead.

This also applies to this line:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
```

5 might be right, since the array length is `6` and you want to terminate before the last index, but this code will break if you use a larger array. Use `arr.length - 1` instead of `5`.

---

This line compares an array element with itself:

```
int result = arr[i].compareTo(arr[i]);
```

Therefore `result` will always be `0`. Change it to either:

```
int result = arr[i].compareTo(arr[j]);
```

or:

```
int result = arr[j].compareTo(arr[i]);
```

Try both approaches to see the difference between them.

---

In your fix above, you're comparing the elements on index `i` and `j`. Therefore you should change this code:

```
if (result == -1) {
    tempVar = arr[j + 1];
    arr[j + 1] = arr[i];
    arr[i] = tempVar;
}
```

to use the correct index of `j`:

```
if (result == -1) {
    tempVar = arr[j];
    arr[j] = arr[i];
    arr[i] = tempVar;
}
```

Your current code compares the elements of `i` and `j` (well, not `j` due to the bug, but you meant that), but your swapping different elements due to the different index `j+1`.